# Use WP_Query() arguments to return current post/page

Tags: php, wordpress, facetwp

I find myself in a strange situation where I need to add the argument "facetwp => true" to a WP_Query loop that returns the current post/page. However, in all of my research I cannot figure out a way to use arguments to return the current post/page. I found some references to using rewind_posts() in order to loop back and match the current ID, but it was all too technical and didn't have examples.

I know that WordPress gets the content for the current page by default, but I have a unique setup where I'm relying on Oxygen Builder, ACF, and FacetWP with Latitude/Longitude fields in ACF (not the Google Maps field) in order to populate a Google Map on single custom post pages. I cannot get the Map Facet to identify the proper query on this page, so I am trying to add a custom code block with "facetwp => true" that returns the current page so that it recognizes the correct query.

For example:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'facetwp' => 'true'
     // Additional arguments to return current post/page
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

I can find all kinds of ways to return other posts/pages using additional arguments, but no luck returning the current page. Can anyone help?!?

EDIT: Now that I re-read my question. It’s not that I need to use arguments to call the post/page, I just need the “facetwp => true” argument to be in the loop. I can rely on any other method to return the current post, it doesn’t have to be arguments that achieve this.

EDIT 2: More research. This seemed somewhat promising but isn't working correctly. Anyone have any thoughts?

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
$current_post_id = $wp_query->post->ID;
echo "The current post ID is: " . $current_post_id;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'court',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_in' => $current_post_id
);

$related_posts = new WP_Query( $args );

while( $related_posts->have_posts() ):
    $related_posts->the_post();
// The Loop
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly you need to have `'facetwp' => 'true'` added to all queries that WP makes internally when loading the page?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier that could be one way to do it yes. I have built a template in Oxgyen Builder for this specific custom post type. If I could somehow add `'facetwp' => 'true'` to the query for this template that may achieve it. However, FacetWP's requirements are pretty specific. My original thought is that I would just insert a PHP code block into this template that calls the current post. Once that is done FacetWP will recognize that post as the primary query. I have achieved it through this method successfully calling other posts, but I cannot get the current post to be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suggestion worked @EmielZuurbier!

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
$current_post_id = $wp_query->post->ID;
echo "The current post ID is: " . $current_post_id;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'court',
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post__in' => [$current_post_id],
    'facetwp' => true
);

$related_posts = new WP_Query( $args );

while( $related_posts->have_posts() ):
    $related_posts->the_post();
// The Loop
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
endwhile;
?>
```

I was able to get it working using the above code and the suggestions you made. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

With the [`pre_get_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/) action hook you can modify the `$query` object that is used for the primary post loop, like in your example, a single `court` page, before the query is actually made.

In the example below the `$query` is modified by adding the `facetwp` property to the query if we're on a single court page, using the main query, and not in the admin environment.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', function($query) {
  if ($query->is_singular('court') && $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin()) {
    $query->set('facetwp', true);
  }
});
```

This should allow you to use the primary post loop without having to create a custom query on your page.

Comment: I was so excited to try this out. Sadly it doesn't work. For some reason my Map Facet is just not recognizing the primary query on the page and will not appear. If I add the required "facetwp-template" class to any element on the page it will appear, however the query is not correct.

You can see in their documentation if we're using a custom query we need to manually add the "facetwp-template" class around our loop:
https://facetwp.com/help-center/listing-templates/custom-wp-query/

Comment: Hmm, that's a bummer. I changed the value of the `facetwp` property to a boolean, since the docs shows the examples like that. Besides that, I took another look at your query in **Edit 2** and noticed that `post__in` should have 2 underscores instead of 1. The value also needs to be an array, so change `$current_post_id` to `[$current_post_id]`. Let me know if any of the above helps.

Comment: Your suggestions worked! I made those two changes to the code and hallelujah it's working. Thank you SO MUCH!!!